# How to fix offending key phrase, that pops up again and again?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, known-hosts

For a github repo I want to update it and I type

```
git fetch --all
```

on the command line, but I am always asked

```
Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'xxx.yyy' differs from the key for the IP address '123.456.789.000'
Offending key for IP in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts:1042
Matching host key in /home/adietz/.ssh/known_hosts:1
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

I found similar questions with the solution to remove the offending line from the file

```
.ssh/known_host
```

but as soon as I repeat the `git` command the line is added to `.ssh/known_host` again, and I am asked over and over again. I even removed the complete file `.ssh/known_host` without luck.

I am still asked that yes/no question **every** time.

Is there any way to get rid of this annoyance? Ubuntu 20.04.4

Comment: Does the key of the server change frequently? Normaly it shouldn't. Are there maybe multiple load balanced servers and you're hitting either one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are editing the wrong file. The message says that the key found in `.ssh/known_hosts` is valid, the offending key is in `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`. Remove it there.

Comment: Ah I see. Yes you are right. fixing is there did solve the problem. The error message is somewhat confusing though...